# tcolorbox and mdframed not working

Tags: color, boxes, tcolorbox, mdframed

I would really like boxes to surround remarks or course refreshers and I want them to take up the whole page width (remarks that arise during an exercise but need to be visually accessible for later use). I would also like to be able to colour them according to category (remark, refresher, proof, example, etc...). Basically fcolorbox does the job, but since there seem to be so many possibilities I was wondering whether I could additionally have the option to adjust horizontal alignment of particular lines without having to affect the whole box content, which doesn't seem to work with fcolorbox.
I found mdframe and tcolorbox online where given examples seemed to fit my aspirations but when I try them myself they don't work :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!5,everyline=true]
        mdframed    
    \end{mdframed}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
        tcolorbox
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

`mdframed` produces a missing left edge except when I zoom in, and `tcolorbox` does nothing.

[image: this]

Here is some info about my setup :
MiKTeX: 2.9.7380
GitInfo: 1cd259c / 2020-04-04 13:37:26
OS: Windows 10 Home, 32-bit, build 18363
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Dan\Nerdy stuff\Latex OpenClassrooms\Latex\miktex\bin
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheck: 2020-04-09 10:22:06
LastUpdate: 2020-04-09 10:26:40

Comment: I have increased the thickness in the addendum. For tcolorbox  I can't help you. The reasons are technical: do you have some error in compiling a .log file to add? **Do you have a basic version of MikTeX?**

Comment: I don't mean to sound too novice, but I don't really know what compiling a log file means, how can I test that ? I don't know whether I have a basic version, I've edited my post with info I got from the MikTex console, at the very bottom of my post.

Comment: Which editor do you compile? Each compilation leaves a trace on the file you are compiling. The .log file (where it tells you what you are compiling and the package that you're using), .aux (auxilium=help).

Comment: I am using TeXnicCenter 2.02, but I have just tried with TexWorks and tcolorbox works. I now have the top line missing in mdframed but again this is resolved by zooming in. Does this diagnosis tell you in any way how I might make this work on TeXcniCenter or should I just switch (hoping there's no new problem on TexWorks) ?

Comment: When lines appears and disappears with zooming the normal culprit is the specific PDF viewer. Check your option for antialiasing and sub-pixel line rendering (they could be called differently). Try with different PDF viewer.

Comment: I sincerely asked for help in the chat room for you. With all my heart I haven't used TeXnicCenter for at least 4 years since they have abandoned the project. I use TeXworks :-). mdframed is an old package that can only give these problems in distant viewing. As soon as you zoom or print the result is fine.

Comment: @Rmano Thank you very much. I'll reciprocate your help.

Comment: @Sebastiano no need at all; PDF viewer quality is really variable and, especially on not so high resolution screen, are a pain in the back. I do not know the status on Windows, but on Linux I always use several different ones to check things...

Comment: @Rmano That's who I am. I really appreciate the help and I feel good.

Answer (score 4):

Have you updated your `LaTeX` distribution? I have added  only `everyline=true` and I have changed your documentclass.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

    \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!5,everyline=true]
        mdframed    
    \end{mdframed}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
        tcolorbox
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Zoom in.

[image]

**Addendum:** On request of the user I have increased the tickness of the border with `linewidth=2pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

    \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!5,everyline=true,linewidth=2pt]%%<---addendum
        mdframed    
    \end{mdframed}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
        tcolorbox
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated MikTex, added "everyline" and changed the document class as you did. The zooming in worked for mdframed (what should I do to correct that, thicken the border ?) but tcolorbox still does nothing.

Comment: @JamesWell I have delete my previous comment.